# How to extract values from list and store it as dictionary(key-value pair)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I need to extract 2 values from this list of dictionary and store it as a key-value pair.
Here I attached sample data..Where I need to extract "Name" and "Service" from this input and store it as a dictionary. Where "Name" is Key and corresponding "Service" is its value.

**Input:**

```
response  = {
'Roles': [
    {
        'Path': '/', 
        'Name': 'Heera', 
        'Age': '25', 
        'Policy': 'Policy1', 
        'Start_Month': 'January', 
        'PolicyDocument': 
            {
                'Date': '2012-10-17', 
                'Statement': [
                    {
                        'id': '', 
                        'RoleStatus': 'New_Joinee', 
                        'RoleType': {
                                'Service': 'Service1'
                                 }, 
                        'Action': ''
                    }
                ]
            }, 
        'Duration': 3600
    }, 
    {
        'Path': '/', 
        'Name': 'Prem', 
        'Age': '40', 
        'Policy': 'Policy2', 
        'Start_Month': 'April', 
        'PolicyDocument': 
            {
                'Date': '2018-11-27', 
                'Statement': [
                    {
                        'id': '', 
                        'RoleStatus': 'Senior', 
                        'RoleType': {
                                'Service': ''
                                 }, 
                        'Action': ''
                    }
                ]
            }, 
        'Duration': 2600
    }, 
    
    ]
}
```

From this input, I need output as a dictionary type.

**Output Format:** { Name : Service }

**Output:**

```
{ "Heera":"Service1","Prem" : " "}
```

**My try:**

```
Role_name =[]
response = {#INPUT WHICH I SPECIFIED ABOVE#}
roles = response['Roles']
for role in roles:
    Role_name.append(role['Name'])
print(Role_name)
```

I need to pair the name with its corresponding service. Any help would be really appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like above response is not a valid ``python dict``.

Comment: Where is ```"John"``` in the data? I cannot see it anywhere.

Comment: What if 'Statement' list has many entries? Should we pair the name with list of services?

Comment: It is valid. I renamed the data for privacy purposes.The Structure of input data is a valid python dictionary.

Comment: @PepperChill The ```)``` is making it invalid though. Not sure if that was intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to write a long line which can reach till the key 'Service'.
And you a syntax error in line **Start_Month': 'January')** and **'Start_Month': 'April')**. You can't have one unclosed brackets.
Fix it and run the following.

This is the code:

```
output_dict = {}
for r in response['Roles']:
    output_dict[r["Name"]] = r['PolicyDocument']['Statement'][0]['RoleType']['Service']

print(output_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Heera': 'Service1', 'Prem': ''}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do like this:

```
liste = []
for role in response['Roles']:
    liste.append(
            {
                role['Name']:role['PolicyDocument']['Statement'][0]['RoleType']['Service'],
            }
            )
print(liste)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your input data is structured kind of strange and I am not sure what the `)` are doing next to the months since they make things invalid but here is a working script assuming you removed the parenthesis from your input.

```
response = {
    'Roles': [
        {
            'Path': '/',
            'Name': 'Heera',
            'Age': '25',
            'Policy': 'Policy1',
            'Start_Month': 'January',
'PolicyDocument':
{
    'Date': '2012-10-17',
    'Statement': [
        {
            'id': '',
            'RoleStatus': 'New_Joinee',
            'RoleType': {
                'Service': 'Service1'
            },
            'Action': ''
        }
    ]
},
'Duration': 3600
},
{
    'Path': '/',
    'Name': 'Prem',
    'Age': '40',
    'Policy': 'Policy2',
    'Start_Month': 'April',
'PolicyDocument':
{
    'Date': '2018-11-27',
    'Statement': [
        {
            'id': '',
            'RoleStatus': 'Senior',
            'RoleType': {
                'Service': ''
            },
            'Action': ''
        }
    ]
},
'Duration': 2600
},

]
}

output = {}

for i in response['Roles']:
    output[i['Name']] = i['PolicyDocument']['Statement'][0]['RoleType']['Service']

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want in a variable called role_services:

```
role_services = {}

for role in response['Roles']:
    for st in role['PolicyDocument']['Statement']:
        role_services[role['Name']] = st['RoleType']['Service']
```

It will ensure you'll go through all of the statements within that data structure but be aware you'll overwrite key-value pairs as you traverse the response, if they exist in more than a single entry!

[A reference on for loops](https://python-course.eu/python3_for_loop.php) which might be helpful, illustrates using `if` statements within them which can help you to extend this to check if items already exist!

Hope that helps